# How to search for merged questions?

Tags: support, search, merged-questions

I would like to search for questions that were merged into another.

However there is no advanced search filter for merged questions, e.g.: `merged:yes`

Is there any combination of search filters to return a result set containing merged questions?

Answer (score 11):

This combination of search filters will return almost all merged questions:

```
is:q locked:yes hasnotice:no migrated:no
```

View [search result](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3Aq+locked%3Ayes+hasnotice%3Ano+migrated%3Ano&searchOn=1).

#### Explanation:

**`is:q`** - to filter by questions (solves an edge case where the other three could return a [locked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19406822/revisions) <sup>(now unlocked)</sup>, `migrated:no` does not filter questions)

**`locked:yes`** - Merged posts are locked. This may not take into account if a mod unlocked a merge source post for some reason.

**`hasnotice:no`** - Most merged posts do not have a post notice. If not included, you get locked posts for other reasons (e.g.: content dispute, community wiki, etc.)

Edge cases:

- This may not take into account if a mod removed the post notice while keeping it locked
- There is a rare chance the post was locked with a post notice before merging ([SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1630505/find-merged-questions-with-active-post-notices))

**`migrated:no`** - If you don't include this you get [migrated questions as well](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3Aq+locked%3Ayes+hasnotice%3Ano&searchOn=1)

#### Notes:

- we can't use `closed` because merged questions can be both opened/closed
- we can't use `duplicate:yes` because questions can be merged without closing as duplicates first (e.g.: [45801447](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45801447/revisions))

Comment: Any ideas why this shows ~80 posts fewer than the merged posts page?: https://stackoverflow.com/annotated-posts?tab=locked&filter=merged That page says 1871 while the search says 1790

Comment: The search you gave is missing some posts. You have to search for (heavily downvoted) [posts with a notice](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Score%3A..-50+is%3Aq+locked%3Ayes+hasnotice%3Ayes+migrated%3Ano&searchOn=1) to find this (heavily downvoted) [merged question that first had a content dispute lock](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35185374/6083675) (for example).

Comment: Thanks @Laurel, I'll add the few edge cases where the search result doesn't work...